# Ctrl + Shift +R is not working in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> is not working in Eclipse for project1 while it is working for project2 on my machine.
While it is working for both the projects for my colleague.
Please help me for the same.

Comment: What perspective are you using? Open Resource is not active in all perspectives.

Answer (score 1):

Window - Preferences - General - Keys. Look if the shortcut is there and if not then just add it.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into a similar problem and the answer may be the same.  When I start up eclipse, the debugger related buttons on the tool bar are lit up even though I just started eclipse and nothing is running.  If you hit the 'stop' button, you get a dialog saying nothing is running, but after you close it, those buttons are greyed out as they should be.  I have found that if I don't hit the stop button several of the key mappings simply don't work.

So, when I first state Eclipse, my tool bar looks like this:

[image]

When it should look like this (and does after I hit 'stop' and clear the dialog):

[image]